# NCO: change the attribute value of variable with a new string containing blank space

Tags: python, bash, time, netcdf, nco

I have a netCDF file `FORCING.nc` which contains a variable `time` with attribute value `units: hours since 2007-12-28 22:00:00`. In python code, it is as following:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
Dataset('FORCING.nc')["time"]
```

and the output is:

```
Out[3]: 
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 time(time)
    units: hours since 2007-12-28 22:00:00
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (13,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used
```

And I want to change the attribute of `units` from `hours since 2007-12-28 22:00:00` to `hours since 1996-01-01 22:00:00`. And `1996-01-01 22:00:00` comes from a variable `$start_date` in bash script.

So I want to use something like:

```
ncatted -a units,time,o,c,'hours since '$start_date FORCING.nc
```

which gives the argument `'hours since '+$start_date` to then catted command, indeed it is `'hours since 1996-01-01 22:00:00'` . But I got the error message like:

```
ncatted: ERROR file start_date not found. It does not exist on the local filesystem, nor does it match remote filename patterns (e.g., http://foo or foo.bar.edu:file).
ncatted: HINT file-not-found errors usually arise from filename typos, incorrect paths, missing files, or capricious gods. Please verify spelling and location of requested file. If the file resides on a High Performance Storage System (HPSS) accessible via the 'hsi' command, then add the --hpss option and re-try command.
```

I guess it is because there is space between "hours since 2007-12-28" and "22:00:00". If I use `ncatted -a units,time,o,c,'hours since 2007-12-28 22:00:00' FORCING.nc`, it works fine. But how can I use `$start_date`? because `start_date` varies each time I run the code...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close! Try

```
ncatted -a units,time,o,c,'hours since '"$start_date" FORCING.nc
```

Shell quoting rules. Can't live with 'em, can't live without 'em.

Comment: Thanks! But could you please show me what's the difference between "" and ''? And what do you mean by ```Can't live with 'em, can't live without 'em```?